# Retrieving Client Information from server end Using C# .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, client-server

I want to retrieve the client PC information at the sender end. When a client sends a request/message at client end in simple socket programming lets say, i want that client to retrieve the information of client PC e.g like which windows is client using , what is the name of client's PC etc.

I have retrieved client IP address using

```
connectionSocekt.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
```

I have searched whole internet and YouTube But i couldn't find any where how to retrieve other information of client PC. Kindly help me with this thing.

Comment: So "No, you *can't* get  much information about a host just by opening a socket".  That's a Good Thing.  There are, however, many many different protocols that allow you to get information about other hosts on the network, including [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/using-wmi), [SNMP](https://www.manageengine.com/network-monitoring/what-is-snmp.html) and [JMX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/index.html).  Q: Does that answer your question?

Comment: I had come across the solution but i don't exactly know how to do it. What i want is that the server can get the all remote host information  like MAC Address, Hard Disk size , Windows used etc etc.
I came to know that after getting the IP Address of the remote host, you retrieve all the information calling the DOS or shell script from your Console application and print all information through some of their commands.
But the thing is that i don't know how to do it.

Comment: No, no, no.  Whatever DOS command you used to use, you definitely want to use WMI (or equivalent) in a C# program in the 21st Century ;)  Here are yet more options available to you: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-get-remote-system-b0c2f178

Comment: Thanks. This link is very useful. But what i need is in C# and With `CMD commands` if possible. I haven't studied  any scripting language or power shell etc.
kindly if that is possible. Thank you so much for the help till now!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get information about a remote host on your local network.

You will *NOT* necessarily get it from some arbitrary "sockets" program: a basic TCP/IP connection simply doesn't have that information .

A client request to a web server, however, might have some of what you're looking for.  Look at [HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), particularly the [User-Agent](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers-user-agent/) header.

Since you're on Windows, you should also look at WMI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page